# Getting full path from the relative path with Argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am writing a small command line utility for my script and I can't figure out how to properly get the full path from the argument.

Here's what I mean.

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-src",
                    required = True, help="path to some folder")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.src)
```

If the user pass the full path, e.g. `"/home/username/projectname/folder"`, everything is fine.

But if the user runs the script from let's say `"projectname"` folder and pass the relative path `"./folder"` I get exactly the same string `"./folder"` while parsing the arguments instead of the full path `"/home/username/projectname/folder"`.

So, I have been wondering if there is some kind of inbuilt functionality in `Argparse` that allows to get the full path from the relative path?

Comment: try `os.path.abspath(args.src)`

Comment: @user3051029 see answer from Alex. regarding your question, I think it should be the accepted answer

Comment: @Tryph sure, if you don't mind it, I'll change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**: The [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55258475/2696355) shows how to make `argparse` manage relative-to-absolute path conversion by simply filling the `add_argument`'s `type` parameter.

---

I do not think argparse provides such feature but you can achieve it using [os.path.abspath](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

```
abs_src = os.path.abspath(args.src)
```

Keep in mind that this will make an absolute path by concatenating the working directory with the relative path. Thus the path is considered relative to working directory.

---

If you want to make the path relative to the script directory, you can use [os.path.dirname](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) on the `__file__` variable and [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build an absolute path from a path relative to your Python script:

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
abs_src = os.path.join(script_dir, args.src)
```

Finally, since joined path can contain tokens such as `.` and `..`, you can "prettify" your built path with [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath):

```
abs_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(script_dir, args.src))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works pretty well for my scenario. Didn't know about this function.

Answer (score 10):

To add onto Tryph's answer, you can specify the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) parameter in the argument declaration. It can take any callable that takes a single string argument and returns the converted value:

```
parser.add_argument("-src",
                    required=True,
                    help="path to some folder",
                    type=os.path.abspath)
```

This returns a string with the absolute path, you could specify your own function as well:

```
def my_full_path(string):
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return  os.path.normpath(os.path.join(script_dir, string))


parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-src",
                    required=True,
                    help="path to some folder",
                    type=my_full_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't our friend [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) simplify this?

```py
from pathlib import Path

abs_path = Path(args.src.name).resolve()
```

`abs_path` is now a `pathlib.PosixPath` object, but it easily casts to a string if needed.